# Optimising partial dictionary key match

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a dictionary which uses a 4-tuple as it's key. I need to find all the keys in the dictionary which partially match some other tuple. I have some code which does this but it's slow and needs optimizing.

Here's what I'm after:

```
Keys:
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5, 2)
(2, 4, 8, 7)
(1, 4, 3, 4)
Match:
(1, None, 3, None)
Result:
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 4, 3, 4)]
```

Current code:

```
def GetTuples(self, keyWords):
    tuples = []
    for k in self.chain.iterkeys():
        match = True
        for i in range(self.order):
            if keyWords[i] is not None and keyWords[i] != k[i]:
                match = False
                break
        if match is True:
            tuples.append(k)
    return tuples
```

- keyWords is a list containing the values I want to match
- self.chain is the dictionary
- self.order is the size of the tuple
- len(keyWords) always = len(k)
- 'None' is considered the wild card
- The dictionary is pretty huge (this method is taking ~800ms to run and about 300mb), so space is also a consideration

I'm basically looking for either optimizations to this method, or a better way of storing this data.

Comment: Can `None`s appear at any position in `keyWords`?

Comment: +1 for asking a question where `reduce` is in the answer.

Comment: Yes, there can be any number of None at any position.

Comment: A small note that might be of use to some people - only calling range() once (and using the range it gives rather than calling it each time in the for loop) reduced the amount of time the function takes to complete by ~50%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just using a database?

I prefer SQLite + [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) even for simple projects, but plain [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) might have a gentler learning curve.

Putting an index on each key column should take care of speed issues.

Comment: This is a really nice idea for a higher-level optimization to my program, thanks! Totally hadn't thought of this :)

Comment: +1 Those who do not use databases are doomed to reinvent them.

Comment: To be fair, the “I'm reinventing a database!” buzzer only rang in my head after I started writing a suggestion involving set intersections...

Comment: An SQL database is rarely the best solution, performance-wise, for datasets that fit in memory, especially if they have limited query semantics like this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can't optimize this further if you store your data in a plain dictionary, since it does not provide anything faster then a sequential access to all elements of your dictionary in some unpredictable order. This means that your solution is not faster then `O(n)`.

Now, databases. Database is not a universal solution to any (complex enough) problem. Can you reliably estimate the speed/complexity of such lookups for a database? If you scroll to the bottom of this reply, you will see that for large data sets database performance can be much worse than a smart data structure.

What you need here is a hand-crafted data structure. There is a number of choices, it strongly depends on other stuff you are doing with this data. For example: you can keep `N` sets of sorted lists of your keys, each sorted by `n`-th tuple element. Then you can quickly select `N` sorted sets of elements matching only one tuple element at position `n`, and find their intersection to get the results. This would give an average performance of `O(log n)*O(m)` where m is an average number of elements in one subset.

Or you can store you items in a k-d tree, this means that you have to pay `O(log n)` insertion price, but you can  do queries like the one above in `O(log n)` time. Here is an example in python, using k-d tree implementation from SciPy:

```
from scipy.spatial import kdtree
import itertools
import random

random.seed(1)
data = list(itertools.permutations(range(10), 4))
random.shuffle(data)
data = data[:(len(data)/2)]

tree = kdtree.KDTree(data)

def match(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        if v != b[i] and (v is not None) and (b[i] is not None):
            return False
    return True

def find_like(kdtree, needle):
    assert len(needle) == kdtree.m
    def do_find(tree, needle):
        if hasattr(tree, 'idx'):
            return list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: match(needle, x),
                                          kdtree.data[tree.idx]))
        if needle[tree.split_dim] is None:
            return do_find(tree.less, needle) + do_find(tree.greater, needle)
        if needle[tree.split_dim] <= tree.split:
            return do_find(tree.less, needle)
        else:
            return do_find(tree.greater, needle)
    return do_find(kdtree.tree, needle)

def find_like_bf(kdtree, needle):
    assert len(needle) == kdtree.m
    return list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: match(needle, x),
                                  kdtree.data))

import timeit
print "k-d tree:"
print "%.2f sec" % timeit.timeit("find_like(tree, (1, None, 2, None))",
                                "from __main__ import find_like, tree",
                                number=1000)
print "brute force:"
print "%.2f sec" % timeit.timeit("find_like_bf(tree, (1, None, 2, None))",
                                "from __main__ import find_like_bf, tree",
                                number=1000)
```

And test run results:

```
$ python lookup.py
k-d tree:
0.89 sec
brute force:
6.92 sec
```

Just for fun, also added database-based solution benchmark. The initialization code changed from above to:

```
random.seed(1)
data = list(itertools.permutations(range(30), 4))
random.shuffle(data)
```

Now, the "database" implementation:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE a (x1 INTEGER, x2 INTEGER, x3 INTEGER, x4 INTEGER)")
db.execute("CREATE INDEX x1 ON a(x1)")
db.execute("CREATE INDEX x2 ON a(x2)")
db.execute("CREATE INDEX x3 ON a(x3)")
db.execute("CREATE INDEX x4 ON a(x4)")

db.executemany("INSERT INTO a VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
               [[int(x) for x in value] for value in tree.data])

def db_test():
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM a WHERE x1=? AND x3=?", (1, 2))
    return cur.fetchall()

print "sqlite db:"
print "%.2f sec" % timeit.timeit("db_test()",
                                 "from __main__ import db_test",
                                 number=100)
```

And test results, reduced for 100 runs per benchmark (for resulting 657720-element set of keys):

```
$ python lookup.py
building tree
done in 6.97 sec
building db
done in 11.59 sec
k-d tree:
1.90 sec
sqlite db:
2.31 sec
```

It also worth mentioning that building tree took almost twice less time then inserting this test data set into the database.

Complete source here: https://gist.github.com/1261449

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could speed it up by maintaining indexes for your keys. Essentially, something like this:

```
self.indices[2][5]
```

would contain a `set` of all of the keys which have `5` in the third position of the key.

Then you could simply do set intersection between the relevant index entries to get the set of keys:

```
matching_keys = None

for i in range(self.order):
    if keyWords[i] is not None:
        if matching_keys is None:
            matching_keys = self.indices[i][keyWords[i]]
        else:
            matching_keys &= self.indices[i][keyWords[i]]

matching_keys = list(matching_keys) if matching_keys else []
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but the range of possible keys is huge - I was using single digit numbers as an example, but in reality the key is a 4-tuple of strings.

Comment: You can still use the same idea - either with the full strings, or with hashes of them if the strings are significantly long. Heck, you could even speed things up a lot by simply storing a single integer checksum of the string as its 'index key'. Even if there are collisions, simply reducing your search space will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

riffing on Amber's answer:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> index = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(set))
>>> keys = [(1, 2, 3, 4),
...         (1, 3, 5, 2),
...         (2, 4, 8, 7),
...         (1, 4, 3, 4),
...         ]
>>> for key in keys:
...     for i, val in enumerate(key):
...         index[i][val].add(key)
... 
>>> def match(goal):
...     res = []
...     for i, val in enumerate(goal):
...         if val is not None:
...             res.append(index[i][val])
...     return reduce(set.intersection, res)
... 
>>> match((1, None, 3, None))
set([(1, 4, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)])
```